# Reference to class file not working

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I'm trying to make a simple RSS feed reader app. I've created a class file with the name "IotdHandler.java" and a public class with the same name. When I try and create a new instance of the class I get the following error: "Unreachable code".

If anyone can point me in the direction of a good tutorial about working with multiple class files I would be very grateful.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.nasa_daily_image, menu);
    return true;
    IotdHandler handler = new IotdHandler();
    handler.processFeed();

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats because you have a return statement before.

Unreachable code has nothing to do with the class/library, is a compiling error because there's no way the code below the "return true" will be executed in anyway, you should get a good Java Book before diving into Android.

Regards!

Comment: We all started not knowing these kind of stuffs, I would recommend you to read a really good Java Book to avoid these kind of issues "Not Related to Android itself". Read Sun Certified Java Programmer SE 6 Study Guide by Kathy Sierra and Bert Bates. AWESOME Books, you'll get better...